# How to display multi selected values of slicer in Card?

Tags: powerbi

I have one slicer and has multi select option on. I need to display the selected values of slicer in Card using measure

Answer (score 1):

You can use Measure = SELECTEDVALUE(TableName[COLUMN_NAME],"No filer") -- No Filter is optional

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/selectedvalue-function

Comment: i want all selected values not single one

Comment: suppose user selected a b c then it should display a,b,c like that

Comment: Try something like, although not work in all scenario... give it a try...  
 IF(ISFILTERED(Column),CONCATENATEX(Table,Column,", "),"No Filter Applied")

Answer (score 0):

Pravin, the important part is to create you Measure correctly, so make sure the formula you are using gets you the result you are expecting.

From Right -> Left:

1- Do a right click in order to create a new measure.

2- Visualization of a "Card"

3- Visualization of a "Slicer"

[image] 
Salu2

Answer (score 0):

[Check out this image how to get the multi select values from a slicer on card visual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYilD.png)

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557